# Most efficient way to replace lowest list values in dataframe in R

Tags: performance, r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, with a list/vector of numbers recorded for each subject for two repetitions of a test item.

```
subj item rep vec
s1 1 1 [2,1,4,5,8,4,7]
s1 1 2 [1,1,3,4,7,5,3]
s1 2 1 [6,5,4,1,2,5,5]
s1 2 2 [4,4,4,0,1,4,3]
s2 1 1 [4,6,8,7,7,5,8]
s2 1 2 [2,5,4,5,8,1,4]
s2 2 1 [9,3,2,6,6,8,5]
s2 2 2 [7,1,2,3,2,7,3]
```

For each item, I want find 50% the mean of rep 1 and then replace the lowest numbers in the rep 2 vector with 0, until the mean of rep2 is less than or equal to the mean of rep1. For example, for s1 item1:

```
mean(c(2,1,4,5,8,4,7))*0.5 = 2.1 #rep1 scaled down
mean(c(1,1,3,4,7,5,3)) = 3.4 #rep2
mean(c(0,0,0,0,7,5,0)) = 1.7 #new rep2 such that mean(rep2) <= mean(rep1)
```

After removing the lowest numbers in rep 2 vector, I want to correlate the rep1 and rep2 vectors and perform some other minor arithmetic functions and append the results to another (length initialized) dataframe. For now, I'm doing this with loops similar to this pseudo code:

```
for subj in subjs:
  for item in items:
     while mean(rep2) > mean(rep1)*0.5:
       rep2 = replace(lowest(rep2),0)
     newDataFrame[i] = correl(rep1,rep2)
```

Doing this with loops seems really inefficient; in R, is there a more efficient way to find and replace the lowest values in a list/vector until the means are less than or equal to a value that depends on that specific item? And what's the best way to append correlations and other results to other dataframes?

**Additional info:**

```
>dput(df)
>structure(list(subj = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L), .Label = c("s1", "s2"), class = "factor"), item = c(1L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), rep = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L), vec = list(c(2, 1, 4, 5, 8, 4, 7), c(1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 
 5, 3), c(6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5), c(4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3), c(4, 6, 
 8, 7, 7, 5, 8), c(2, 5, 4, 5, 8, 1, 4), c(9, 3, 2, 6, 6, 8, 5
 ), c(7, 1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 3))), .Names = c("subj", "item", "rep", 
 "vec"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want this dataframe as the output (with rep1 vs. rep2 correlation and rep1 vs new rep2 correlation).

```
subj item origCorrel newCorrel
s1 1 .80 .51
s1 2 .93 .34
s2 1 .56 .40
s2 2 .86 .79
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add in your question the output of `dput(subjs)` as well as the desired output for this dataset.

Comment: Sorry, you said "I have a dataframe with a list/vector of numbers"; I assumed that was `subjs`.  Please provide the `dput` of your `data.frame`

Comment: Your pseudo code disagrees with your narrative a bit. I think you want the inequality reversed in the pseudocode.

Comment: @Seth since rep1 was cut in half, it is probably less than rep2... until enough of rep2's values have been set to zero. I think Amyunimus has the inequality as intended.

Comment: OK, thanks @GSee , I realize I made a mistake in my answer that I think is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical strategy to get rid of loops is to make all your computations that are on the subsetted data into their own function, then call that function in an `aggregate` or `apply` function.

```
two.cors=function(x,ratio=.5) {
  rep1=unlist(x[1,][['vec']])
  rep2=unlist(x[2,][['vec']])
  orig.cor=cor(rep1,rep2)
     while(mean(rep2) > mean(rep1)*ratio) {
   rep2[    which(rep2==min(rep2[which(!rep2==0)]))]=0
    }
  c(orig.cor,wierd.cor=cor(rep1,rep2))
}
```

I want to use daply so get `plyr`, could have used aggregate or an base `*apply` function

```
library(plyr)
```

Then call the function on you dataset

```
 daply(df,c("subj","item"), .fun=function(x) two.cors(x,ratio=.4) )
```

this output can be reformatted but I left that to you because I think you need additional statistics out of the `two.cors` function

Comment: If I wanted to specify an additional argument for two.cors (e.g. ``two.cors=function(x,param)``), how would I add that to the ``daply()`` line?

Comment: I edited my post to pass an argument through the daply into the two.cors function.